# Como trasladar consulta sql a eloquent laravel 5.5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

He tratado de pasar esta consulta

```
select usuario_ad, nombre 
from usuarios 
where usuario_ad in (select username from users 
where users.refer="adminpal" union select "adminpal");
```

a eloquent

```
$result = Usuario::where('refer', 'adminpal')->pluck('usuario_ad', 'nombre')
```

Pero aun no logro lo que quiero, alguien sabe como puedo completarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre de este modo:

```
DB::table('usuarios')
  ->select('usuario_ad', 'nombre')
  ->whereIn('usuario_ad', function($query){
    $query->select('username')
          ->from('users')
          ->where('users.refer', 'adminpal')
          ->union('adminpal');
})->get();
```

- Usando el *facade* `DB` para poder ejecutar sentencias SQL
- Como segundo argumento del método `whereIn()` pasamos una función anónima que contendrá la subquery
- No olvides importar el namespace `DB` al inicio de tu controller con `use DB`

Comment: Gracias Aprendiz... "creo que soy yo el aprendiz",  y si tengo la consulta asi..

Comment: select usuario_ad, count(usuario_ad) from usuarios where usuario_ad in (select username from users where users.refer="Thor" union select "Thor") group by (usuario_ad);

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con [DB::raw()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) cuando son consultas muy complejas no es necesario complicarse tanto y optar por una query directa.

```
$query = 'select usuario_ad, nombre 
from usuarios 
where usuario_ad in (select username from users 
where users.refer="adminpal" union select "adminpal")';

$result = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
```